# How to add audio file to my form?

Tags: c#, events, audio

I want to add an audio file to my form so that when any button event occurs, if anything is clicked then the audio file will play.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WPF, Silverlight or ASP.NET?

Comment: in generally: add a audio file to the project, write or copy a class that can read and play the audio and put the call to that class in any click event, that will get it working.

BTW: 0% looks tempting not to answer...

Comment: Increase Your acccept rate !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code for adding audio?

```
private void playSoundFromResource(){
    SoundPlayer sndPing = new SoundPlayer(SoundRes.GetType(), "Ping.wav");
    sndPing.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a much more better way to write your code is to put the following code in form1.cs

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SoundPlayer Mcd = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Mcd\Desktop\abcd.wav");
        Mcd.PlayLooping();
    }
```